# Serializing object with arrays with objects to JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an object like this:

```
obj = {"arr1" : [], "arr2" : ['z1', 'z2', 'z3'], "arr3" : []};
obj['arr2']['z2'] = 'z8';
```

It has nested arrays, and each value of can be an object with or without arrays, etc.

How to get a JSON for that? JSON.stringify would lose 'z8' value.

Comment: Your object is invalid: `arr2` should be an object, not an array.

Comment: Have you tried to execute this code? The first line isn't even valid JavaScript.

Comment: To elaborate on @VisioN's comment: In JavaScript, Objects always have a combination of `key:value`, Arrays never do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JSON (by standard) you have [Arrays, Objects, values and strings](http://www.json.org/), arrays are not Objects like in JavaScript. JSON is only a data-interchange format, you don't have a base prototype like in JavaScript where almost everything is an object and have properties.

So, if you want to have a property `z3` of `z2` you have to make `z2` an object.

Answer (score 2):

arr2 is an array. You cannot use it like a map.

```
var obj = {"arr1" : [], "arr2" : ['z1', {'z2':'z3'}], "arr3" : []};
obj['arr2'][1]["z2"] = 'z8';
alert(JSON.stringify(obj));​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8JYNB/)